# Center an <h1> tag inside a <div>

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have the following `<div>` inside a `<body>` tag:

```
<div id="AlertDiv"><h1>Yes</h1></div>
```

And these are their CSS classes:

```
#AlertDiv {
    position:absolute;
    height: 51px;
    left: 365px;
    top: 198px;
    width: 62px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}

#AlertDiv h1{
    margin:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

How can I vertically and horizontally align an `<h1>` inside of a `<div>`?

`AlertDiv` will be bigger than `<h1>`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can add `line-height:51px` to `#AlertDiv h1` if you know it's only ever going to be one line. Also add `text-align:center` to `#AlertDiv`.

```
#AlertDiv {
    top:198px;
    left:365px;
    width:62px;
    height:51px;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:black;
}

#AlertDiv h1 {
    margin:auto;
    line-height:51px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

The demo below also uses negative margins to keep the `#AlertDiv` centered on both axis, even when the window is resized.

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/KaXY5](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/KaXY5/)**

Comment: Yes, it will be only one line. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This is really the only truly valid answer: you make height and line-height the same and then the vertical-align CSS attribute will work. After searching high and low for that this is all that came up.

Answer (score 12):

On the hX tag

```
width: 100px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: Why is the width attribute required for the auto left/right to work?

Comment: in my case, juste by adding width, as the text was already align center, it worked! Thanks Very simple answer that works for most cases.

Answer (score 11):

There is a new way using transforms. Apply this to the element to centre. It nudges down by half the container height and then 'corrects' by half the element height.

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
```

It works most of the time. I did have a problem where a `div` was in a `div` in a `li`. The list item had a height set and the outer `div`s made up 3 columns (Foundation). The 2nd and 3rd column divs contained images, and they centered just fine with this technique, however the heading in the first column needed a wrapping div with an explicit height set.

Now, does anyone know if the CSS people are working on a way to align stuff, like, easily? Seeing that its 2014 and even some of my friends are regularly using the internet, I wondered if anyone had considered that centering would be a useful styling feature yet. Just us then?

Comment: I use this technique to horizontally align some elements in situations where `text-align:center;` does not work correctly. `position:relative; left:50%;transform:translateX(-??%)...` "??" has to be tweaked depending on how wide the element is.  I know it's kinda hacky, but seems to work on the screens I've tried it on so far.

Comment: I found that using `transform:translateX(-??em)` is, actually, more reliable across various screen sizes than `??%`

Comment: Aside - new video on centering by Chrome Devs team at Google is pretty cool https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncYzTvEMCyE

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="AlertDiv" style="width:600px;height:400px;border:SOLID 1px;">
    <h1 style="width:100%;height:10%;text-align:center;position:relative;top:40%;">Yes</h1>
</div>
```

You can try the code here:

http://htmledit.squarefree.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could add padding to the `h1`:

```
#AlertDiv h1 {
  padding:15px 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Started a **jsFiddle** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jby3m/3/).

It seems the *horizontal alignment* works with a `text-align : center`.  Still trying to get the vertical align to work; might have to use `absolute` positioning and something like `top: 50%` or a pre-calculated `padding` from the top.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table-cell` in order to render the div as a table cell and then use `vertical-align` like you would do in a normal table cell.

```
#AlertDiv {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can try it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/KaXY5/424/