# How do I vertically center an H1 in a div?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

First of all, my apologies. I know there are various solutions posted for this issue here, but for the life of me I can't get any of them to work.

For a responsive website I'm trying to center an h1 in a div.

Centering horizontally is not an issue, but I'm having problems getting it centered vertically. Presumably I'm doing something wrong or misunderstanding the explanations I found here (or maybe both).

So as I'm probably interpreting earlier solutions given the wrong way, could someone please explain what exactly I have to add to the code beneath to get the h1 to center vertically?

(To make this question relevant to as much people as possible, I've already stripped the code of all my previous attempts to do so myself.)

CSS:

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

#section1 {
min-height: 90%; 
text-align:center
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="section" id="section1">
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Get rid of the `h1` `padding` and `margin` and use `vertical-align` on the `div`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK That won't work.

Comment: Set your line-height to 1.2

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes, I've just tried it on fiddle. Bad comment. Haha

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254793/center-a-h1-tag-inside-a-div

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/TNb39/

Comment: @VikasGhodke: Yes, the solution you and Pete gave was the one I was looking for. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 155, accepted):

you can achieve vertical aligning with `display:table-cell`:

```css
#section1 {
    height: 90%; 
    text-align:center; 
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

#section1 h1 {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CMHx4/)

**Update - CSS3**

For an alternate way to vertical align, you can use the following css 3 which should be supported in all the latest browsers:

```css
#section1 {
    height: 90%; 
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/CMHx4/24/)

Comment: Nice! align-items: center; was what I was looking for vertical alignment. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for CSS3 alternative!

Comment: Nothing worked in my scenario. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this with the `display` property:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#section1 {
    width:100%; /*full width*/
    min-height:90%;
    text-align:center;
    display:table; /*acts like a table*/
}
h1{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:middle; /*middle centred*/
    display:table-cell; /*acts like a table cell*/
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a3Kns/

Comment: Cheers! Went with Pete's solution, but essentially this works the same. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I've had success putting text within span  tags and then setting vertical-align: middle on that span. Don't know how cross-browser compliant this is though, I've only tested it in webkit browsers.

Comment: Thanks! Suppose this should work too. Would accepted answer help you ensure it's cross-browser compliant?

Comment: Looking back at my code, it's actually quite hacky, so the above `table` answer is better. My method requires an extra span set to `width: 0;`. But, in case you or anyone else is interested, see the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LeedsEbooks/jWc68/)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id='sample'>
<span class='vertical'>Test Message</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #sample 
    {
        height:100px;
         width:100%;
        background-color:#003366;
        display:table;
        text-align: center;

    }
    .vertical 
    {
           color:white;
         display:table-cell;
        vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Fiddle : [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8mnds/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is a solid well-supported way to center an h1 tag inside div.

```
<div class="section" id="section1">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
</div>
```

This is the OP:s HTML. Let's keep it like that.
Now working with CSS we can add display flex and some properties. Here is a working code snippet that shows how flexbox can do vertical alignment.

```css
#root {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#section1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 90%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  /* this does align h1 if h1 is wider than its containing text */
}

#section1>h1 {
  flex: 1;
  /* this makes the h1 take all available width in its containing div, and makes text-align: center property work inside section1 */
  background-color: #666333;
  align-self: center/* this is finally the property that vertically aligns the h1 title inside its containing div */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>Demo</header>
<div id="root">
  <div id="section1">
    <h1>Title Centered</h1>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Since the accepted answer's CSS3 option vertically aligns the containing div and not the h1 tag as requested, this answer shows how that h1 can be vertically aligned inside a pre-sized, larger containing div.

Answer (score -1):

Just use padding top and bottom, it will automatically center the content vertically.