# Center several h inside div css

Tags: css, centering

I am currently trying to center several h inside a div:

```
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</div>
```

The point is, the size of my div can change. How can I achieve this in css ?
I have already found a few topics on the subject as : [Center a H1 tag inside a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254793/center-a-h1-tag-inside-a-div)

But it hasn't been useful.

Thanks.

Comment: both vertical and horizontal or just horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by centering but `text-align:center` will center the ext.

If you need to have the headings **next** to each other then `inline-block` is the simplest answer.

```css
div {
  text-align:center;
  }

.aligned h1, .aligned h2 {
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</div>

<div class="aligned">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way to centering element vertically are to use the table/table-cell behavior like:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;
    display: table;
}
h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Horizontally, just use a text-align: center :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Pik_at/06d5aLqd/

Comment: Just put your headings into an element like <header> and give him the table-cell behavior ;)
Update: http://jsfiddle.net/Pik_at/06d5aLqd/1/

Comment: Changing the HTML makes this easy, but there are cases where you can't (your HTML comes from external source and you can't alter it)... it is not clear if it is a requirement for OP or not. BTW add it to your answer, that otherwise is only half-correct

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```css
.block{
    /* decor */
    padding:0 20px;
    background:#666;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    text-align:center;
    /* important */
    min-height:220px;
    width:260px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.block:after{
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    height:220px; /* the same as min-height */
    width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 0 0 -5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.block .centered{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="centered">
    
    <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```